# Coeffcient in the solution of system of differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let us suppose a system of first order linear differential equation as follows:

$\frac{d}{d t}\begin{pmatrix}
  \rho_{00} & \rho_{01} \\
  \rho_{10} & \rho_{11}
\end{pmatrix} = \Gamma\begin{pmatrix} \rho_{11} & -\rho_{01} \\ -\rho_{10} & -\rho_{11} \end{pmatrix}$

with assmed intial condition for just some numbers $\rho_{ij}(0)\in \mathbb{R}$

Its analytic solution is

$
\begin{align}
\rho_{00}(t)&= \rho_{00}(0) + \rho_{11}(0) (1 - \exp(-\Gamma t)) \\
\rho_{01}(t)&= \rho_{01}(0) \exp(-\Gamma t) \\
\rho_{10}(t)&= \rho_{10}(0) \exp(-\Gamma t) \\
\rho_{11}(t)&= \rho_{11}(0) \exp(-\Gamma t)
\end{align}
$

As the method that Ron Gordon mentioned below, why the solution for $\rho_{00}(t)$ is not

$\rho_{00}(t) = \rho_{00}(0) + \Gamma^2 \rho_{11}(0) (1 - \exp(-\Gamma t))$ ?

Since $\frac{d}{d t} \rho_{00}(t) = \Gamma \rho_{11}(0) \exp(-\Gamma t)$ then $\rho_{00}(t) = C - \Gamma^2 \rho_{11}(0) \exp(-\Gamma t)$ and $C=\rho_{11}(0) + \Gamma^2 \rho_{11}(0)$

Comment: I am assuming that $i$ and $\Gamma$ are constants here? Slightly confusing here ;).

Comment: @Chinny84 I updated it to original form, and for simplicity delete $i$ and $\Gamma$, yes they are just constant

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you have for the $\rho_{00}$ equation:

$$\dot{\rho_{00}} = \rho_{11}(0) e^{-t} \implies \rho_{00}(t) = C - \rho_{11}(0) e^{-t}$$

where, upon applying the initial condition, we find that $C = \rho_{00}(0) + \rho_{11}(0) $.  Substituting this into the equation for $\rho_{00}$ produces the desired result.

Comment: For $\dot{\rho_{00}} = \rho_{11}(0)e^{-t}$, is it because we substitute the solution for $\rho_{11}(t) = \rho_{11}(0)e^{-t}$ , and what if $\frac{d}{d t}\rho_{11}(t)$ has some parts other than $\rho_{11}$

Comment: Then in general, four coupled 1st-order ODEs are equivalent to a single, 4th-order ODE.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the method. And to compared with solution in notes, it seems a missing coefficient if we put a coefficient to original equation. The details are updated to the question.